# DynamoDB : query global secondary index on non-key attributes

Tags: php, database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query `global secondary index` by applying a condition on non-key attributes of `GSI`. I have tried below code and its not working.

**Code :**

```
$result = $this->dbClient->query(array(
                        'TableName' => 'myTable',
                        'IndexName' => 'myIndex',
                        'AttributesToGet' => array('id'),
                        'KeyConditions' => array(
                            // Key attribute
                            'userId' => array(
                                    'ComparisonOperator' => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
                                    'AttributeValueList' => array(
                                        array(Type::NUMBER => $value)
                                    )
                                ),
                            // This is non-key attribute
                            'length' => array(
                                    'ComparisonOperator' => ComparisonOperator::LE,
                                    'AttributeValueList' => array(
                                        array(Type::NUMBER => $upperLimit),
                                    )
                                ),
                            ),
                        ));
```

**EDIT :**
I get error message

```
Query key condition not supported
```

Comment: How is it not working?  What is the Exception you get back?

Comment: @Geek, what i have read is that we cannot query on non key attribute, that is why we use GSI so if you want to query on length then create new GSI with "length" as hash or range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

- For a query on a table, you can only have conditions on the table
     primary key
         attributes. You must specify the hash key attribute name and value as an EQ
         condition. You can optionally specify a second condition, referring to the range
         key attribute.
- For a query on an index, you can only have conditions on the index key attributes.
  You must specify the index hash attribute name and value as an EQ condition. You
  can optionally specify a second condition, referring to the index key range
  attribute.

Comment: please example of non-key attribute in dynamodb

Answer (score 0):

You can only query on key attributes. You need to create a GSI on "length" - The reason GSI exist is for this purpose.